# php create folder owner/group

Tags: php, owner, chown

I'd transfer my site to linux hosting, Its has an issue on uploading image to the system's auto create folder which permission is chmod 0777, I found that its always make the uploading failed because of owner/group is in www-data, how could it change owner/group to 'root' in order to upload the image into the folder?

```
$media_path = "../upload/".$nextid;

if(file_exists($media_path)){
//do nuthing

}else{

mkdir($media_path, 0777);
chmod($media_path, 0777);
chown($media_path, "root");
chgrp($media_path, "root");
```

}

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You should be changing the file executing the upload to `www-data` grp, and 0777 is abit steep 0755 would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `chown` unless you are root. But creating the folders with `0777` is sufficient to allow anyone to write to them.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't write file into the folder unless i create folder thought FTP by self, the folder ownership would be in 'root'